# Getting InnerText ignoring script node by using Html Agility Pack in C#

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have following page from which I want to get a list of proxy servers from a table:

> http://proxy-list.org/spanish/search.php?search=&country=any&type=any&port=any&ssl=any

Each row in the table is an ul element. My problem is when obtaining the first li element which associated class is "proxy" from the ul element. I want to obtain the IP and Port so I perform an InnerText but as li element has an script child node, it returns the text of the script node.

Below an image of the structure of the page:

[image]

I have tried below code using Html Agility Pack and LINQ:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string page = webClient.DownloadString("http://proxy-list.org/spanish/search.php?search=&country=any&type=any&port=any&ssl=any");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);

List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='table']")
            .Descendants("ul")
            .Where(ul => ul.Elements("li").Count() > 1)
            .Select(ul => ul.Elements("li").Select(li =>
                {
                    string result = string.Empty;
                    if (li.HasClass("proxy"))
                    {
                        HtmlNode liTmp = li.Clone();
                        liTmp.RemoveAllChildren();
                        result = liTmp.InnerText.Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = li.InnerText.Trim();
                    }
                    return result;
                }).ToList()).ToList();
```

I can obtain a list which each item is a list containing the fields (Proxy, País, Tipo, Velocidad, HTTPS/SSL) but field proxy is always empty. Also I am not getting at all the "País" and "Ciudad" columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because those values are injected into the DOM by JavaScript after page load.  Actually the value inside the `Proxy()` is a Base64 representation of what you are looking for.

In the image you have posted above the value `MTQ4LjI0My4zNy4xMDE6NTMyODE=` decodes to `148.243.37.101:53281`

The raw parsed string you are feeding to the Agility pack only contains the `Proxy` field...

```
    <div class=\ "table-wrap\">\r\n
        <div class=\ "table\">\r\n
            <ul>\r\n
                <li class=\ "proxy\">
                    <script type=\ "text/javascript\">
                        Proxy('MTM4Ljk3LjkyLjI0OTo1MzgxNg==')
                    </script>
                </li>\r\n
                <li class=\ "https\">HTTP</li>\r\n
                <li class=\ "speed\">29.5kbit</li>\r\n
                <li class=\ "type\">
                    <strong>Elite</strong>
                </li>\r\n
                <li class=\ "country-city\">\r\n
                    <div>\r\n
                        <span class=\ "country\" title=\ "Brazil\">
                            <span class=\ "country-code\">
                                <span class=\ "flag br\"></span>
                                <span class=\ "name\">BR Brasil</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <!--\r\n                     -->
                        <span class=\ "city\">
                            <span>Rondon</span>
                        </span>\r\n </div>\r\n </li>\r\n </ul>\r\n
            <div class=\ "clear\"></div>\r\n
```

Using the following code:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var docResult = client.GetStringAsync("http://proxy-list.org/spanish/search.php?search=&country=any&type=any&port=any&ssl=any").Result;
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(docResult);
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"Proxy\('(?<value>.*?)'\)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        var stuff = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='table']")
        .Descendants("li")
        .Where(x => x.HasClass("proxy"))
        .Select(li =>
        {
            return li.InnerText;
        }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in stuff)
        {
            var match = reg.Match(item);
            var proxy = Encoding.Default.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(match.Groups["value"].Value));
            Console.WriteLine($"{item}\t\tproxy = {proxy}");
        }
```

I get:
[image]